# Analyzing the usage of particular variable in COBOL program using NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, cobol, text-analysis

I am trying to extract the impact information,as a result of changing a particular variable.For example, if  there is a change in Variable X, then if  Y and Z are the dependent variables like below:

```
Move X to Y
Move Y to Z
```

Then I will print list containing  dependent variables as in the order they appear in the MOVE statement like `X Y Z`

My program extract all the MOVE statement and write it to a file.Read that file line by do search for the variable X and its dependencies line by line.There are many drawback to my algorithm. One major flaw is it cannot handle backward reference.
Second thing is if the Variable X occur in ADD statement i need to do a separate  logic.

Can this be solved by NLTK? Any pointers or link to start with, will be more handy.As of now I don't have access to any Mainframe and all the programs are in `.txt` format in Windows.

Comment: Your question is three weeks old and your last comment one week old. How did you solved this issue?

Comment: Not resolved completely.Working on it using Cobol compiler.

Comment: OK. If one of the answers to your questions "worked best" for you (and you don't intend to post a better answer yourself in the next hours) please mark it - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (this helps to both find answers and to find questions that are not answered yet)

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to extract the impact information, as a result of changing a particular variable.

COBOL uses variables in a record layout (*similar* to a C `struct`) and allows overlapping memory (*similar* to a C `union`). Therefore `X` may have an impact for `MOVE VAR1 TO VAR2`.

You have to have a look at the record structure first and then check if sub-fields / parent fields exist and check for these references, too.

Not to even speak of `[COPY] REPLACING`...

Something that can help you to know where a variable is referenced is a cross-reference. You may use a COBOL compiler on PC that allows you to compile "mainframe COBOL sources" and produces a symbol listing showing the definition of the variables.
(Doing only the parsing not the actual compilation.)

The only (GPL) free compiler that will do this is [GnuCOBOL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnucobol/). Compile your sources with `cobc -std=ibm-strict -t prog.lst -tsymbols -Xref -fsyntax-only program1.txt` and you'll get something like the following:

```
SIZE  TYPE           LVL  NAME                           PICTURE

00080 GROUP          01   VAR1
00075 ALPHANUMERIC   02   X                              X(75)
00005 ALPHANUMERIC   02   X2                             X(5)
```

This symbol listing shows: `X` is part of `VAR1`.

```
NAME                           DEFINED                                    REFERENCES

VAR1                           26       41      153    *160    *206     272     285     322
X                              46      *44      258
X2                             47       164     212     249     269    *286
```

This cross-reference shows that `VAR1` is defined in line 26 and referenced in lines 41, 153, 160, 206, 272, 285, 322 (the entries with the asterisk are references that write to the variable), similar for `X`.

> ... in the order they appear in the MOVE statement ...

As a COBOL program often does "structured jumps" (via `PERFORM` / `EXIT SECTION`, `EXIT PERFORM`, `EXIT PROGRAM`, `GOBACK`) and "unstructured" `GO TO` the order will only be correct if you can trace the program. Many COBOL runtimes allow you to do this but you'd have to feed it with real data...).

For these reasons I'd answer your question

> Can this be solved by NLTK?

With "no". Better pre-process the sources with a COBOL compiler that supports a listing with a symbol listing and a cross-reference included and the dialect that was used with the sources, then do a simple parse of the resulting tables which of course is possible in Python.

Comment: @VishnuRajalekshmi: if this answer "works" for you please mark it as accepted - or comment for any issues you see.

Comment: it would work.But in my scenario i have more than 10K programs recompiling all the program is another tedious work.Any other alternative for this.

Comment: @VishnuRajalekshmi It would be even more tedious work to do this parsing on your own (still possible).
Note: I don't recommend to recompile all the programs but to do the parsing (for `cobc` this would be `-fsyntax-only`, I'll edit my answer to add this).
Before doing this you have to **COBOL-parse** 10k+ programs with additional copybooks (possibly mutliple times) - after doing this you only have to **text-parse** 10k listing files.